# TreeView notification error when the TVN_ENDLABELEDIT notification handler is being debugged

Tags: winapi, treeview

I have a TreeView that allows users to change the labels. To do this I have a handler for the  TVN_ENDLABELEDIT notification that reads the TVITEM from the NMTVDISPINFO structure and sends the TVM_SETITEM message.

All of this works fine EXCEPT in one particular case: when for the sake of debbuging I interrupt the execution of the handler BEFORE returning with 0 from the notification.

What happens in this case is that if another notification arrives before the handler returns with 0, i.e., before I'm done debbuging it, the TreeView will crash the application because it will call a rutine at a null pointer.

This means that the TreeView somehow trusts the handler from finishing before other event gets processed.

Has anyone experienced this kind of behavior? I think the OS should be a little bit more robust; shouldn't it?

Comment: The user interface thread can only do *one* thing at a time.  There will never be any "other event" that gets processed until your callback completes.  Do not "interrupt" callbacks with the debugger, whatever that might mean.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Your comment actually answered my question. Don't know how to acknowledge this other than with this comment.